# change callback function

Tags: jquery

```
$('input.plan-select').change(function() {
  // alert('Handler for .change() called.');
  $(".subscription", this).toggleClass('selected');
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XPVVp/

It doesn't toggle the class for some reason, I'm not sure why it isn't working.

Comment: An `input` is a void element: it *cannot* contain any other element. Therefore using that as a context for the selector will, and *can*, never find an element. What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the `.subscription` select is not a child of the `input` element which is how your code is written.  Instead the `.subscription` element is a parent so you need to use the right jQuery operations to find the proper parent like this:

```
$('input.plan-select').change(function() {
  // alert('Handler for .change() called.');
  $(this).closest(".subscription").toggleClass('selected');
});
```

`.closest()` will look up the parent chain until it finds the first parent that matches the selector.

Working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/krTER/

Answer (score 0):

Because the `input` is inside the `.subscription` div element and not vice versa. So there is no `.subscription` element below `this` ... nothing to apply `toggleClass()` to. What exactly do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input.plan-select').change(function() {
  // alert('Handler for .change() called.');
  $([".subscription", this]).toggleClass('selected');
});
```

seems to be working

Comment: Ah yes, but I wonder why mine doens't work? I'm pretty sure I used that syntax before

Comment: I was wondering the same, hence my doubtful comment - "Seems to be working"

Comment: Actually been a while since i used jquery. Looking through its docs, jQuery(selector, [context]); therefore jQuery(selector, ...) will not work. You can however provide jQuery(selectorArray); That's why your method doesn't work. this is being used as the context.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know really what you wanted to do with that selector... 
You can use the "this" selector to get the radio button and then go up by one level with the .parent() directive.

```
$('input.plan-select').change(function() {
    // alert('Handler for .change() called.');
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('selected');
});
```

You can also use

```
$('.subscription').toggleClass('selected');
```

if you have just one element of said class.